# while reloading the page css styles get discarded

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, routes, styling

I am working on a react project to display the item listing page that get item by passing id in Link path from API...it is working initially fine with css but once i reload the page the styling get discard

```
<ul class='categories-list clearfix'>
          {props.isLoading
            ? "Loading..." : topCategory.map((allCategories) => allCategories.is_top_category === 'yes' ? (
            <li key={allCategories.id}>
              <i class='category-icon'>
                <img src={allCategories.icon_url} alt='' />
              </i>
              <h3>
                <Link to={{ pathname:`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/ads-listing/${allCategories.id}`,state:{categoryId: allCategories.id}}}>
                  {allCategories.name}
                </Link>
              </h3>
            </li>
          ): "")}
        </ul>
```

i am very confused why it is happening, it will be very thankful if i get a solution here

Comment: Where do you have your css?

Comment: Included in index.html

Comment: what are you using for your back-end? sounds like SPA isn't properly configured